# Не меняется date.timezone в php.ini

Tags: php.ini, php

Доброе время суток всем.
Вылезла такая ошибка :

```
Warning: phpinfo(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings.
 You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function.
 In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier.
 We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.
```

Полез в php.ini (сразу скажу, сижу на ubuntu 13.10). Меняю значение date.timezone = Asia/Jerusalem. Перезапускаю apache.
Но почему то в phpinfo Default timezone стоит UTC. Как бы не пытался поменять это, все остается без изменений. 
варнинг получается убрать только с помощью date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jerusalem'); но не хочется пихать это в каждый файл.

У когото есть идеи как можно это исправить ( задать date.timezone глобально ) ?

Comment: Может вы не раскомментировали `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jerusalem');` в php.ini?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант в настройках виртульного хоста в апач прописать для корневой директории сайта

```
php_value date.timezone Asia/Jerusalem
```

Comment: А можно поподробнее, как это сделать в Ubuntu ?

Comment: Ubuntu, не Ubuntu - какая разница? Вы же где-то конфигурацию виртуального хоста для apache задаете?

В Debian-based дистрибутивах (куда Ubuntu тоже входит) обычно ссылки на конфиги для включенных вирт. хостов находятся в `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`. Там как минимум лежит файлик для дефолтного хоста `default`.

Ищите в конфиге для своего хоста что указано в `DirectoryRoot`, например `/var/www/`, потом ищете для нее секцию описания, обрамленную в `<Directory /var/www/>...</Directory>`, и туда вставляете то, что написано в ответе.

Незабудьте перегрузить после этого апач! ;-)